# C# Graphics for large image and large drawable objects

Tags: c#, forms, graphics, drawing

now i am here to ask for best practice about working with graphics.
I am using windows forms.
So - 
At base i have large image (3.7k x 5.3k pixels)
On top of that i want to draw graph - Vertexes and edges (vertex is like circle and edge is arrow between circles)

At the moment i used picturebox with SizeMode set to Zoom, so i can increase picturebox widht and height to act like "zoom option".
in Paint event i draw vertexes which intersects with with DisplayRectangle. Same with edges.
I have option to add edges - while i move mouse i invalidate() picturebox so it looks like animation( i draw another Vertex on mouse location).

Problem is - when i have around 10k vertexes, frames per second drops to like 1 or 2. 
If you know some good ways to make this thing smooth and optimised, please share with me :)

Comment: You need to use something more suited for this work like [DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/aa937781).

Comment: You may also want to consider OpenTK - http://www.opentk.com.

Comment: only draw what needs to be drawn.  You don't have to redraw the entire image, only what changed.